How to access previous route in Next.js 14 using App Router?
Existing threads are mostly relevant to the Pages router.
I know that with react router I'm able to do this:
const history = useHistory();
const { pathname } = useLocation();

history.push('/', { from: pathname }) 

And then access the previous path like so:
const Home = (props) => {
   console.log(props.location.state.from);
}

But how do I achieve this in NextJS 14 using the App Router?
I tried accessing asPath prop bbut apparently it was removed:
const usePreviousRoute = () => {
  const { asPath } = useRouter();

  const ref = useRef<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = asPath;
  }, [asPath]);

  return ref.current;
};


This isn't something that Nextjs app router supports. The problem with this approach is that Nextjs is fundamentally a server/client hybrid framework with an emphasis on server-side rendering (SSR).
There is a discussion on this topic on Github.
According to one of the maintainers:

[this feature] needs a great proposal on how to prevent users from shooting themselves in the foot using history state given you can't access history state server-side for example, it would be very easy to cause hydration issues.

Nextjs has a section in the docs on Using the native History API. Either way, you might have to come up with your own solution.

Thank you. This is very sad. It seems like I'm going to need state management just to pass the previous route string.

You can create a custom context with the previous route as a value by listening on router events.
Define the context:
'use client';

import { useContext, useEffect, useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

export const useNavigationContext = () => useContext(NavigationContext);

export const NavigationProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return <NavigationContext.Provider value={navigation}>{children}</NavigationContext.Provider>;
};

const useNavigation = () => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  const [currentRoute, setCurrentRoute] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [previousRoute, setPreviousRoute] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = `${pathname}?${searchParams}`;
    setPreviousRoute(currentRoute);
    setCurrentRoute(url);
  }, [pathname, searchParams]);

  return { previousRoute };
};

const NavigationContext = createContext<ReturnType<typeof useNavigation>>({
  previousRoute: null,
});

Use Provider in RootLayout:
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <NavigationProvider>
         {children}
        </NavigationProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

Consume in Client Component:
'use client';

import Link from 'next/link';

import { useNavigationContext } from '@/contexts';

const BackButton = () => {
  const { previousRoute } = useNavigationContext();

  return <Link href={previousRoute ?? '/'}>Go back</Link>;
};

export default BackButton;


You can get this with the referrer header, provided you have set up your headers to allow this.
In next.config.ts:
headers: {
  ...other headers...
  { key: 'Referrer-Policy', value: 'origin-when-cross-origin' },
}


In your server component:
import { headers } from 'next/headers'

const BackBtn = () => {
  const headersList = headers()
  const referer = headersList.get('referer')
}

Or in a client component you could use document.referrer.
Please note that on hot reload in dev mode, the referrer will be the current page. But other than that this is the workaround I found works best.

you can do it by using useRouter from next/navigation;
use router.back() to go to back
const handleCloseProfile = () => {
      router.back();
};


Using Zustand
path-store.ts:
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { create } from "zustand";

interface AsPathStoreType {
    prevAsPath: string | undefined;
    currentAsPath: string | undefined;
    setAsPaths: (
        _prev: string | undefined,
        _current: string | undefined,
    ) => void;
}

const useAsPathStore = create<AsPathStoreType>((set) => ({
    prevAsPath: undefined,
    currentAsPath: undefined,
    setAsPaths: (prev, current) =>
        set({ prevAsPath: prev, currentAsPath: current }),
}));

/** Hook to get prevAsPath and currentAsPath */
export const useAsPath = () => useAsPathStore((state) => state);

/** Get the current state outside of React components */
export const getAsPath = () => useAsPathStore.getState();

/** Initializes prevAsPath and currentAsPath (use in layout or Client Provider) */
export const useAsPathInitializer = () => {
    const pathname = usePathname();
    const { currentAsPath, setAsPaths } = useAsPathStore();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (currentAsPath !== pathname) {
            setAsPaths(currentAsPath, pathname);
        }
    }, [pathname, currentAsPath, setAsPaths]);
};

export default useAsPathStore;


and then use the store:
const { prevAsPath, currentAsPath } = useAsPathStore();


The cleanest solution for me was using sessionStorage and usePathname


  
const pathname = usePathname();

//storing the pathnames when the value changes. 
useEffect(() => {  
    storePathValues();
  }, [pathname]);

  function storePathValues() {
    const storage = globalThis?.sessionStorage;
    if (!storage) return;

    // Set the previous path as the value of the current path.
    const prevPath = storage.getItem("currentPath");
    

    storage.setItem("prevPath", prevPath ?? "/");
    // Set the current path value by looking at the browser's location object.
    storage.setItem("currentPath", globalThis.location.pathname);
  }



  // you can get the prevPath like this
 const prevPath = sessionStorage.getItem("prevPath");
 



